# how to set an http time out in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to set a timeout duration for an http call in flutter? I have purposely shutdown the web services server to test, and my app just sits there with the circular progress indicator spinning.

Is there a way to set a timeout so the app can gracefully exit the http call with an error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add timeout method after post/get/put ...

````
final response = await this
        .httpClient
        .post(
          '~~~~~'
          headers: config,
          body: json.encode(data),
        )
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: timeout));
    ```
````

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help.