# How to deal with HTTP connection timed out crashes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, connection-timeout, flutter-http

So I have a method that uses the [Flutter HTTP library](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and is responsible for calling HTTP requests to the server with code like this:

```
Future<List<DataModel>> fetchData() async {
  try {
    var url = Uri.parse('${baseUrlParse}myapipath');
    var request = await http.get(url);

    var data = jsonDecode(request.body);

    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Catch ${e}');
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

This code runs fine and has no issues.
It got to the point where when I have no internet connection or server connection fails, the app freezes, and an error file appears (*if you're debugging in VS Code*), called `http_impl.dart`, and the error snippet goes something like this:

```
onError: (error) {
// When there is a timeout, there is a race in which the connectionTask
// Future won't be completed with an error before the socketFuture here
// is completed with a TimeoutException by the onTimeout callback above.
// In this case, propagate a SocketException as specified by the
// HttpClient.connectionTimeout docs.
if (error is TimeoutException) {
  assert(connectionTimeout != null);
  _connecting--;
  _socketTasks.remove(task);
  task.cancel();
  throw SocketException(
      "HTTP connection timed out after $connectionTimeout, "
      "host: $host, port: $port");
}
_socketTasks.remove(task);
_checkPending();
throw error;
});
```

I have tried to implement from [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51489701/9039350) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62409970/9039350), but when I make a request but have no connection, this error still occurs.

How to deal with this problem?
What I want is, if there is a problem with HTTP either there is no connection, or it fails to contact the server, then I can make a notification..

Is there something wrong with my code?
Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You re throw the exception in your code,
   You need to catch exception where you call to this method like this.

   try {
   await fetchData();
   } catch (e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   }
2. You can stop VS Code catching unhandled exceptions from this way
   https://superuser.com/a/1609472

Comment: I use `retrhrow` because i follow [dart's suggestion](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_rethrow_when_possible.html), but it's my fault for not really understanding what is the difference between using throw and retrhrow when use it inside the `catch` block..